# Why dom4j document object convert XML EOL \r\n to \n

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, dom4j

I am parsing xml string using DOM4J jar (I have tried 1.6.1 & 2.0.2) below is my sample code

```
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader("<root xml:space='preserve'>\r\n<emp>\r\n<name>raj</name>\r\n</emp>\r\n</root>"));
Document document = null;

try {
    document = reader.read(inputSource);
} catch (DocumentException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}       
String st = document.asXML(); //When I debug I can see below value in this st variable
//<root xml:space='preserve'>\n<emp>\n<name>raj</name>\n</emp>\n</root>
```

Why its coverting XML EOL (End of Line) from \r\n to \n ?

If I want to preserve same EOL as "\r\n", Is there any option available ?

Answer (score 0):

Mandated by the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-line-ends):

> To simplify the tasks of applications, the XML processor must behave
>   as if it normalized all line breaks in external parsed entities
>   (including the document entity) on input, before parsing, by
>   translating both the two-character sequence #xD #xA and any #xD that
>   is not followed by #xA to a single #xA character.

You can set the line separator used when writing XML documents:

```
OutputFormat#setLineSeparator(String)
```